# How to define default where clause on a table in oracle

Tags: java, oracle

There are some query that have same part of where clause on.

Query one:

```
select [some-selected column] 
  from [TABLE_NAME]
 where [its-own-where-clause]
   and [shared-where-clause]
```

Query two:

```
select [some-selected column] 
  from [TABLE_NAME]
 where [its-own-where-clause]
   and [shared-where-clause]
```

Query three:

```
select [some-selected column] 
  from [TABLE_NAME]
 where [its-own-where-clause]
   and [shared-where-clause]
```

.
.
.
.

Query n:

```
select [some-selected column] 
  from [TABLE_NAME]
 where [its-own-where-clause]
   and [shared-where-clause]
```

As you can see there are two parts in the where-clause, the first one is belong to its own business of query and the second one is shared between all of these querys.
It is clear that the all of above query must be changed when `[shared-where-clause]` is changed.

I want to put the shared-section of where-clause in which the change of it is applied to all of this querys.

Is it possible in oracle?

Comment: [Developing and Using Stored Procedures](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28843/tdddg_procedures.htm). Have fun!

Comment: Without stored procedure. is it possible?

Comment: Maybe views. But your use case is a bit strange. Maybe a concrete example would help.

Comment: I haven't used it in quite a while, but I think [sqlj](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31227/overview.htm) is still included (and can do that). I second the request for a concrete example.

Comment: You can only do this with dynamic SQL. Which means you need to wrap it in a stored procedure or some other programmatic contrivance (client side assembly, SQL/J if you are fond of the retro, etc).

Comment: Also, why did you tag you question `[plsql]` if you don't want a stored procedure as  a solution?

Comment: Certainly defining a view and referring to that instead of the table (as in Andreas' answer) lets you add any `where` clause you want. Or, you could look at [Row-level security](https://mwidlake.wordpress.com/2012/11/15/row-level-security-part-1/), which lets you construct a `where` clause dynamically according to your own rules.

Answer (score 3):

Create a VIEW.

Example:

```sql
create table PERSON (
    PERSON_ID    number(10, 0)  not null primary key,
    PERSON_NAME  nvarchar(100)  not null,
    AGE          number(3, 0)   not null,
    GENDER       char(1)        not null check(GENDER in ('M', 'F'))
);

create view MALES as
select PERSON_ID, PERSON_NAME, AGE, GENDER
  from PERSON
 where GENDER = 'M';

create view FEMALES as
select PERSON_ID, PERSON_NAME, AGE, GENDER
  from PERSON
 where GENDER = 'F';
```

Now we can query various age groups of male persons without repeating the shared condition on `GENDER`.

```sql
select *
  from MALES
 where AGE between 0 and 19;

select *
  from MALES
 where AGE between 20 and 49;

select *
  from MALES
 where AGE >= 50;
```